# SQL Compact 4.0 crashing

Tags: sql-server-ce, task-parallel-library

I have application which do multiple accessing to DB (SqlCompact 4.0). 
And sometimes application crashed with the next record in Event Viewer.

```
Application: MyApp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethodsHelper.SafeRelease(IntPtr ByRef)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethods.SafeRelease(IntPtr ByRef)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ReleaseNativeInterfaces()
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.Dispose(Boolean)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.Finalize()
```

P.S. Multiple accessing means that there are N tasks(Task Parallel Library) which add records in DB.

Comment: thread synchronisation issue....?

Comment: You must have a SqlCeConnection per thread, and make sure to release all Commands, as they are not thread safe

Comment: If it is synchronize issue, then how to check locked or unlocked DB from task?

Comment: ErikEJ, yes I have SqlCeConection per thread (task) but it does not make sense, issue still appears ..

Comment: To be clear here, did you really download the new SqlCe 4 (still CTP ?) Or do you use the SqlCe installed with VS2010?  Check the version of the System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

Comment: I've got the same issues right now - but I let EF handle the connections so not sure how to really check this

Comment: Please let me know if you ever got to the bottom of this - I'm having a similar problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825209/sql-server-compact-edition-4-accessviolationexception).